# Using Hibernate with an existing Database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm looking how to use hibernate with shared database, mapping objects but without affect previous data, schema, tables in order to avoid loss of data. How to configure it for read-only

`"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none"`  provide this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply omitting the entry of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` will suffice.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787365/hibernate-creating-columns-in-the-database-by-itself/51787852#51787852) is one related answer.